# Use URLConnection instead of HttpClient in android studio

Tags: mysql, android-studio

Is there any way to convert this code into URLCOnnection instead of using Httpclient ? Im using API23 and HTTP CLient is not supported anymore. I have a hard time using URLCOnnection because almost all the tutorials uses HttpClient for connection. thanks

```
  public class SigninActivity  extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String>{
  private TextView statusField,roleField;
 private Context context;
 private int byGetOrPost = 0; 

 //flag 0 means get and 1 means post.(By default it is get.)
 public SigninActivity(Context context,TextView statusField,TextView roleField,int flag) {
  this.context = context;
  this.statusField = statusField;
  this.roleField = roleField;
  byGetOrPost = flag;
}

protected void onPreExecute(){

}

 @Override
 protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
    if(byGetOrPost == 0){ //means by Get Method

  try{
     String username = (String)arg0[0];
     String password = (String)arg0[1];
     String link = "http://myphpmysqlweb.hostei.com/login.php?username="+username+"& password="+password;

     URL url = new URL(link);
     HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
     HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
     request.setURI(new URI(link));
     HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
     BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

       StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
       String line="";

       while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
          sb.append(line);
          break;
        }
        in.close();
        return sb.toString();
     }

     catch(Exception e){
        return new String("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
     }
  }
  else{
     try{
        String username = (String)arg0[0];
        String password = (String)arg0[1];

        String link="http://myphpmysqlweb.hostei.com/loginpost.php";
        String data  = URLEncoder.encode("username", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(username, "UTF-8");
        data += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("password", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(password, "UTF-8");

        URL url = new URL(link);
        URLConnection conn = url.openConnection(); 

        conn.setDoOutput(true); 
        OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream()); 

        wr.write( data ); 
        wr.flush(); 

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;

        // Read Server Response
        while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
        {
           sb.append(line);
           break;
        }
        return sb.toString();
     }
     catch(Exception e){
        return new String("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
     }
  }
```

}

```
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result){
  this.statusField.setText("Login Successful");
  this.roleField.setText(result);
```

}
}

Comment: It looks like part of your code is already using URLConnection. Is that part not working?

Comment: its working but the code still have the HttpClient,HttpGet and HttpResponse which is also not supported in api23. how can i remove it and make the code running? thanks:)

Answer (score 0):

This is the basic format for URLConnection that I merged from some working code of mine with yours. If you fill in your code where I've specified, it should work.

```
//-------------------

         String username = (String)arg0[0];
         String password = (String)arg0[1];
         String link = "http://myphpmysqlweb.hostei.com/login.php?username="+username+"& password="+password;

         InputStream is = null;

         try {

               URL url = new URL(link);
               URLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();


               is = urlConnection.getInputStream();

               BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);

        //FILL IN YOUR CODE HERE!
        //FILL IN YOUR CODE HERE!

        } catch(Exception e){
          return new String("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        }

//-------------------
```

Comment: Also, you may want to change your if / else to a switch / case statement.

Comment: Thanks for this Sir :) I will try this.